# Need a Htaccess Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I am getting some errors on my site and need a 301 redirect for my urls that are like so:

https://firstnamelastname.example.com/the-wall to go to https://example.com/new-wall/firstnamelastname where firstnamelastname is any names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^the-wall/?$ http://%2/new-wall/%1 [L,NC,R=301]
```